# Changing current logged in user password [MVC]

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

So i'm making a back End admin dashboard, and i'd like to add a functionality for current users to be able to change their passwords when they're logged in. Below is my relevant code for the `Account Settings` Page where the change password will be taking place.
The user information is all stored in a model database called `LoginDataModel` I just can't work out for the life of me how to get the current logged in user to be able to change his/hers own password and then log them out to be able to log in with the new password? I've even tried using the Edit part from the UserManagement CRUD application however still nothing.

```
public class UserManagementController : Controller
{
    private UserDatabaseEntities db = new UserDatabaseEntities();


    public ActionResult AccountSettings(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        Login login = db.Logins.Find(id);
        if (login == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(login);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AccountSettings([Bind(Include = "Password")]Login login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            User.Identity.GetUserId();
            db.Entry(login).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(login);
    }
}
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="container col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="AssemblyName">New Password :</label>
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 300px;">
                <div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "New Password" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="width: 200px; "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>Save Changes</button>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" style="width: 100px;">Delete</a>
    </div>
}
```

Hope you can help!

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Identity? Or some other authentication/authorisation provider? (I you are creating your own you will probably leave lots of security holes: don't do that.)

Comment: @Richard I've got it in the using area in my UserManagementController however i don't know if it's set up or configured properly. I'm new to MVC as a whole

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using asp identity and want to change password of user then first you need to create reset password token 

string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
string token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(userId);

And then use that token to reset password 

var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(userId, token, newPassword);
```